# Xcode problema con Tap Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift

estoy haciendo un proyecto de fin de grado y no soy capaz de conseguir que se muestre el tap bar como pantalla inicial después de hacer un login, no se si se podría hacer pero cada vez que lo enlazo sale así , y al iniciarlo no se muestra como pantalla principal, si no que se puede salir fácilmente de el. Debería de verse como en la segunda imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Puedes agregar el código? Debes hacer el segue desde el `ViewController` no desde el botón.

Comment: Muestra el código sobre como realizas el login, un ejemplo de hacerlo es la siguiente respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224895/9825937